# Programs in background keep shutting down, Android 5.0.2 Lollipop, LG G2 mini, LG-D620r

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, ram, lg, lg-g2

I have the `LG G2 mini`, model number `LG-D620r`, smart phone on which `Android 5.0.2 Lollipop` runs. Every since the phone updated to this version of Android, it keeps shutting down programs that are in the background.

For instance, if I have a navigation program running, and for a moment use another program, I cannot resume the navigation program. It just restarts which takes a lot longer.

What can I do to retain the programs running in the background instead of them being shut down all the time?

Comment: Don't forget to take into account device's 1GB RAM (only) and the apps' ever-increasing appetite for memory.

Comment: @Firelord Indeed, this is unfortunately always the case. I'm still supposed to install an app with which I can monitor the memory usage. Any recommendations?

Comment: Recommendations formally are off-topic here. But you can get good results on [softwarerecs.se]. Anyhow, see if [OS Monitor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.eolwral.osmonitor&hl=en) helps to monitor the memory usage.